# Speech to text command execution in an angular app

Tags: angular, speech-recognition

I am about to create an angular app that would implement a service worker and mainly used on mobile phones. 
Once the app is open, I want it to continuously listen for spoken commands, such as "create note", "list customers".

What technologies are out  there that would help me achieve this?

I am starting to look at Google speech to text, but can't find any examples with Angular and it seems as though you can't constantly listen for commands.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The have the apis https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/. With the apis you can hit the using angular httpClient. Maybe you will have to be using an observable to be listening all the time

Comment: Have you ever heard about Google Actions. Basically you can make custom Google Assistant requests based on your app. If you are interested you can take a look here: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-assistant-quick-start/

Comment: I like the look of Google Actions, however, that seems as though it only works on Android. I need the speech recognition to work on Android and ios, and even PCs